# Python popup dialog class with checkbox

Tags: python, class, dialog, popup, tkinter

so I designed this dialog box to be popped up. But I'm having difficulty writing how the variable would be set for a checkbutton. I have done popups with entry fields before but this is causing issues. The way it is now, it says there is no self.answernum in self. Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: This is the code that worked

```
class MyDialog(tkinter.simpledialog.Dialog):

    def body(self, master):

        instructions = Label(master, text="Write stylesheet to the xml files?").grid(row=0)
        self.answerreturn = IntVar()
        self.answer = Checkbutton(master,variable=self.answerreturn)
        self.answer.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def apply(self):
        root.form=(self.answerreturn.get())
```

Comment: Create `self.answernum` before trying to use it.

Comment: Thank you, that was part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not TK expert but: If you execute `apply()` before `body()`, `self.answernum` is not defined yet.